# How to Send notification using firebase

Tags: android

I am new in android development. I am try to send notification using firebase. But i got some error.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.

> File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: there is one file `google-service.json`. When you create new app in firebase. You have to download that file and put it in your app folder.

Comment: What have you tried? None of us can help you unless I have something to work with, in particular a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). A great way to explain this is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Also, do check out the [FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931) and [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Answer (score 1):

Open https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592#android
this link.

Follow instructions for download configuration file.

Download your `google-service.json` file.

Put it in your app at following  location.

**YourAppRootFolder** > **app** > put **google-service.json** here

Compile Your project and Run.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create Google services JSON file by providing your credentials like your Unique SHA-1 Key and all the step by step guide of whole configuration is provided on this link: 
https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592#android

you need to download this file and put it in your App package. and try to clean and rebuild project again.

I suggest you also to check udacity cource's this video tutorials are made to learn firebase from very basic they have mentioned all things step by step.
you can get this free cource on this link:

https://www.udacity.com/course/firebase-essentials-for-android--ud009